# unable to connect to rabitmq streams getting RabbitMQ.Stream.Client.StreamSystemInitialisationException: 'no endpoints could be reached' error

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-stream

i am trying to create a new rabbitmq stream  where my rabbitmq is installed in docker.

Bellow are the steps which i implemented.

1. installed RabbitMQ in docker under the TCP port 5672
2. enabled rabbit stream and stream management
3. installed rabbitmq.stream.client nuget in my project
4. ```
   creating connection as below
   ```
5. ```
   var config = new StreamSystemConfig
   {
       UserName = "guest",
       Password = "guest",
       VirtualHost = "/"
   };
   // Connect to the broker and create the system object
   // the entry point for the client.
   // Create it once and reuse it.
   var system = await StreamSystem.Create(config);

   const string stream = "my_first_stream";
   ```
6. when i execute i am getting bellow erro

   RabbitMQ.Stream.Client.StreamSystemInitialisationException: 'no endpoints could be reached'

Can anyone please tell me the solution of this error?

Thank you Anil

I wanted to connect to stream and create stream and send messages to stream.

Answer (score 1):

Check again that you enabled the stream plugin.
You can do so by running the command via the container terminal:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stream
```

Or via docker exec:

```
docker exec rabbitmq rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stream
```

Make sure to expose stream default port 5552 and **localhost** via the environment (-e) option, for example:

```
docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 -p 5552:5552 -e RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS='-rabbitmq_stream advertised_host localhost' rabbitmq:3.11-management
```

Comment: Many examples provide incorrect command line parameters. The last one should be a space instead of an equal sign. Thank you